# Echoing an environment variable, keeping newlines intact?

Tags: bash, command-line, sh

This

```
a="1
2
3"
echo $a
```

produces a single line of output.

```
1 2 3
```

How can I display `$a` keeping line breaks intact?

Comment: Quote it: `echo "$a"`

Comment: @anubhava: That's an answer, not a question (unless you can find an earlier version of this and close as dupe instead).

Comment: @anubhava, perfect!  Submit it as an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think that will be duplicate of some earlier question but I am not able to find it.